# How do I initiate Storybook?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, storybook, npx

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/react/en/get-started/) to set up a Storybook

It tells me to run the following commands:

```
# Create our application:
npx create-react-app taskbox
cd taskbox

# Add Storybook:
npx -p @storybook/cli sb init
```

However, after the third command it gives me

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "<last-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\8504" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\npm- 
cache\_logs\2019-11-04T14_32_25_838Z-debug.log
Install for [ '@storybook/cli@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

This looks like some kind of cache issue, so I've tried clearing my cache and reinstalling node. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

you didn't run npm init ......  package.json file is needed

Comment: @mruanova that guide seems to work now. I also tried it earlier and it didn't work then, but that was before I reinstalled node

Comment: I added a comment before pointing out that this answer does not answer my question in any way. Someone has removed my comment, and left this answer. I find this quite irritating.

Also they removed @mruanova's comment so my surviving comment no longer makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue and as you mentioned it was related to the cache and I executed below commands and it is working fine

```
yarn cache clean --force
npx -p @storybook/cli sb init -f
```